# Dependent FQL query with Facebook Batch Request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I amusing Facebook's Batch method unfortunately the second query does not work once there are 2 0r more results from the first query. I am trying to get the ids of people who liked a post.

```
batch:[{
    "method":"GET",
    "name":"get-stream",
    "omit_response_on_success": false,
    "relative_url":wallid+"/feed?date_format=U&limit=2"
},{
    "method":"POST",
    "depends_on":"get-stream",
    "relative_url":'method/fql.query?query=SELECT+user_id+FROM+like+WHERE+post_id=  {result=get-stream:$.data.*.id}'
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
WHERE+post_id+in+({result=get-stream:$.data.*.id})
```

There at the end? Or if you really want just one post to be involved set the limit to 1?